# Why wont tkinter destroy the window

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

```
import random, math, tkinter


def main():
    window = tkinter.Tk
    signInButton = tkinter.Button(
        text="Sign in",
        command=lambda: signIn(window),
    ).pack()


def signIn(mainWindow):
    mainWindow.destroy()


main()
```

this is the code it wont close the window though, please help

I tried many things and nothing worked

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't even open a window. If one corrects it so it does open a window, it does also destroy it.

Comment: Well, a window will open, because one is needed to contain the Button you create - but `window` is not that window, because you didn't actually *call* `Tk()`.

Comment: @jasonharper If a window does open, it will immediately close...

Comment: You will have to instanciate Tk like so: `window = tkinter.Tk()` then you have to set this window as the buttons master: `signInButton = tkinter.Button(master=window, textext="Sign in", command=lambda: signIn(window)).pack()` and last you have to invoke the mainloop at the end of your `main()` function with: `window.mainloop()`

Answer (score 0):

Read up a little about classes and instances and then come back to this snippet and try to understand it and why what you did was not working:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Button


class LoginApp(Tk):  # Create own class inheriting from Tk
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  # instantiate Tk → same as window = tkinter.Tk() but window is now self
        Button(  # as your button instance is never used storing it in a variable is obsolete
            master=self,  # this connects the Button to the window we created
            text="Sign in",
            command=self.destroy  # just call destroy from the button directly
        ).pack()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = LoginApp()  # instantiate newly created class
    app.mainloop()  # without entering the mainloop nothing will be displayed or responsive
```

Comment: It is not a good design/practice to call `.mainloop()` inside `__init__()`.

Comment: That is true! Normaly i would suggest to store a reference when instantiating the class like `app = LoginApp()` and then call `app.mainloop()` in the `__name__` conditional. But i thought it might be more comprehensive for someone new to undestand that `mainloop` is a method of the Tk instance stored in self, same as `destroy`...

Comment: If you want to teach someone new, definitely it is not recommended..

Answer (score 0):

`window = tkinter.Tk()`

You are using `window = tkinter.Tk`. This is simply the class, and not an instance.
Hence when you call `window.destroy()` you are doing `tkinter.Tk.destroy()`, missing the `self` argument.

Jan_B's answer is more comprehensive but this is the simplest fix.